# I have react tabs code working perfectly but I need to change the html structure

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

I have react tabs code working perfectly but I need to change the html structure to match the below one. Is it possible to bring the tab content after the `<a>` tag to maintain my html structure?

https://jsfiddle.net/9e767txs/9/

```or-tag-here
<div className="sports-tab-container">
  <ul>
    <li role="presentation" className="sports-setup-ico first-time-active ft-active-tab">
      <a href="javascript:;" className="sports-tab-header">
        <h2>sports player</h2>
        <p className="sports-subtitle">Days 1 and 2</p>
      </a>
      <div className="sports-tab-content">
        <p className="sports-large-text ft-day1 ft-day2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" className="sports-invest-ico">
      <a href="javascript:;" className="sports-tab-header">
        <h2>car selling</h2>
        <p className="sports-subtitle">Approx. Day 3</p>
      </a>
      <div className="sports-tab-content">
        <p className="sports-large-text ft-day1 ft-day2">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when </p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change a small CSS Style:

[Live link](https://jsfiddle.net/ashikjs/9e767txs/11/)

**Make:** `display: Block to inline-block`

```
.tabs__labels li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: can you tell me how to change html structure

Comment: @texirv I don't get your point, also Please make more details about your question. WHat you mean by **HTML Structure**.